# Because iphone doesnt cache images over 25kb should I use individual images?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, css-sprites

Im currently creating a sprite for my retina display media query, with it being for iPhone 4 the images are doubled in size which considerably increases the file size. The elements I particularly want to enhance are the buttons and main logo. combining these make the sprite very large so should I just save each button individually keeping them all under 25kb?

Here is an article for anyone who may not know about this 25kb limit: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/02/06/iphone-cacheability/

All advice welcome and thanks

Comment: That article is from Feb 2008 - does it still apply?

Comment: Yeah I was a little sceptical about the date, but then i posted a question about image sprites a month or so back and i got the same response. Will look further into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This limit might not be true. I recommend benchmarking this yourself.

Reasoning: http://uxformobile.com/mobile-browse-cache-image-size-limitations

Comment: The article is almost 4 years old (Feb 2008) - perhaps a bit of more recent testing needs to be done :)

Answer (score 3):

One way I can think to get around this is to use the [HTML5 Cache Manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#manifests) to force Safari to download your sprite and cache it as an HTML5 offline object.